# Batch If/Else Simple

Tags: batch-file

```
echo Changez les phrases ave l'inversion.
pause
echo Use proper capitalization, and a period at the end.
pause
echo L'etudiant a besoin d'aide.
set /p FrenchInv=Write the inversion: 
if %FrenchInv%==A-t-il besoin d'aide? goto FDPA
else echo A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.
pause
```

I get an error if I type in the wrong answer, although I thought that the else echo would return "A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.", rather than a syntax error. 
And is it possible to put in a c with a cedilla - this thing : ç?
I get some weird symbol when I try to echo français.
I'm an english student btw.

It's okay if you don't know french. I personally suck at it.

Comment: To write `ç` use this `‡`

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%FrenchInv%"=="A-t-il besoin d'aide?" (goto FDPA) else (
 echo A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.
)
pause
```

or

```
if "%FrenchInv%"=="A-t-il besoin d'aide?" goto FDPA
echo A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.
pause
```

Note that you need to `"quote strings containing separators line spaces in an if"` and that the quotes are required on each string (both sides of the `==` operator)

The `else` is not required (as in the second example) since if the comparison proves `false` then the `goto` will not be executed and the procedure will progress to the next line.

The parentheses are required in order for `cmd` to correctly parse the command and see `else` as a keyword. The `) else (` sequence must ba all on the same physical line, so

```
if "%FrenchInv%"=="A-t-il besoin d'aide?" (goto FDPA
 ) else (
  echo A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.
)
pause
```

and

```
if "%FrenchInv%"=="A-t-il besoin d'aide?" (
  goto FDPA
 ) else (
  echo A-t-il besoin d'aide? Is the correct answer.
)
pause
```

would also be valid.

Note also that `if /i` allows the comparison to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Really? What other things can you use for if statements? And, thanks a lot.

Comment: From the prompt, `if /?` will show other choices. For instance, you can have other comparison-operators like `equ neq lss gtr leq geq` (equal/note equal/less/greater/less or equal/greater or equal)